# Kotlin Script (.kts) - How to divide it into multiple files?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

I have a Generator.kts file. When I execute it using:

```
kotlinc -script Generator.kts
```

everything works as expected.

However, now my script has grown and I need to separate that class into multiple files.

I did that but when I try to execute it again I get the following errors:

```
Generator.kts:8:23: error: unresolved reference: CSVReader
        val csvData = CSVReader().readCSV()
                      ^
Generator.kts:10:23: error: unresolved reference: Folders
        val folders = Folders()
                      ^
Generator.kts:14:9: error: unresolved reference: KeyStore
        KeyStore().generateKeyStoreFile(
```

Basically it fails to find all of the classes I created (CSVReader.kt, Folders.kt and KeyStore.kt). All those classes are in the same folder (including Generator.kts).

How can I run a Kotlin script that uses multiple files?

Comment: I think you should have a look at this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11618

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could either compile all your sub-scripts into an artifact and add it to the classpath

Or you could use a third party tool like [kscript](https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript) to include them on the fly into your master script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env kscript

@file:Include("utils.kt")

val robustMean = listOf(1.3, 42.3, 7.).median()
println(robustMean)
```

For details and examples see https://github.com/holgerbrandl/kscript#ease-prototyping-with-include

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor of kscript.